# How to clear an environment created within an R package?

Tags: r, package

I have an R package, in which I create a new environment with:

```
.COOLENV <- new.env(parent=emptyenv())
```

At some point I would like to clear this environment entirely and just set it anew. But when I call the above line again, the environment is still populated with the variables and is not new and empty.

Is there a way to just clear it completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From outside .COOLENV:

```
rm(list=ls(envir = .COOLENV), envir = .COOLENV)
```